# Run in bash, string as command does not work (Duplicity)

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos-7, duplicity

I am using Duplicity to backup my server into another.

Since there are several servers, I want to create a bash script that runs with `cron` doing by folder (and server) separation. For this I made the montage of the command in string:

```bsh
printf -v DulicityCMD 'duplicity --log-file %s --progress --no-encryption --include="/etc" --include="/var/log" --include="/var/db" --include="/var/www" --include="/home" --exclude="**" / scp://duplicity@myhost.com:22//home/duplicity/backups/%s' $LOG_FILE $VPSNAME

echo $DulicityCMD

# THIS
$DulicityCMD

# OR THIS
sudo $DulicityCMD
```

If you display the content of `$DulicityCMD` with `echo` it will look something like this:

```bsh
duplicity --log-file /var/log/duplicity/backup.log --progress --no-encryption --include="/etc" --include="/var/log" --include="/var/db" --include="/var/www" --include="/home" --exclude="**" / scp://duplicity@myhost.com:22//home/duplicity/backups/myhost
```

When typing this command, exactly like what is displayed with `echo`, everything works perfectly. However, when running it *from* the variable, within `bash`, it does not work.

Even if I run this with `sudo`, or as the root user, it does not work.
The output of the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/duplicity", line 1546, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/bin/duplicity", line 1540, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/bin/duplicity", line 1375, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1131, in ProcessCommandLine
    set_selection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 969, in set_selection
    sel.ParseArgs(select_opts, select_files)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/selection.py", line 268, in ParseArgs
    self.add_selection_func(self.glob_get_sf(arg, 1))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/selection.py", line 434, in glob_get_sf
    sel_func = self.glob_get_filename_sf(glob_str, include)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/selection.py", line 485, in glob_get_filename_sf
    raise FilePrefixError(filename)
FilePrefixError: "/etc"
```

When I use `eval`, I don't get this error, but it loses root rights, and does not run properly.  Because I need to use the output of this in conjunction with another command (sendmail) using `|`.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

This is a problem of proper string quoting.  When you run from the command line with something like:

```
duplicity --include="/etc"
```

the `"/etc"` will be passed to the underlying program as `/etc` because the `"`'s will have been stripped by the shell.  But when you do something like:

```
DuplicityCMD='duplicity --include="/etc"'
$DuplicityCMD
```

The `"/etc"` is passed exactly as that.  This is due to the fact that, when you defined your variable `DuplicityCMD`, you explicitly asked that the `"` be included by enclosing it inside of `'`.  I would suggest removing the `"` as they look to be largely unneeded.

([More Info: How to escape quotes in shell?](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell))

Comment: (1) Try again.  The command you show will (try to) run a command called `--log-file ` with arguments `$LOG_FILE --progress --no-encryption --include=/etc --include=/var/log --include=/var/db --include=/var/www --include=/home --exclude='**' / scp://duplicity@myhost.com:22//home/duplicity/backups/$VPSNAM` and environment variable `DuplicityCMD` set to `duplicity`. (2) If a person is having a problem with quotes, please don’t suggest removing the quotes except as a last resort.

Comment: What? As discussed in [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), we have on-going problems here on [SU] and on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](//unix.stackexchange.com) of people not quoting things that they should quote — e.g., guinalz didn’t quote `$LOG_FILE` and `$VPSNAME`.  But your answer looks like you’re saying, “This is a problem of proper string quoting.  …  I would suggest removing the `"` …”.  We don’t want to teach people to *remove* quotes when they have a problem.

Comment: P.S. Your command now fails because of the `--exclude='**'`.

Comment: @G-Man. Thanks for the info, helpful.  Yet more of the lore of this place.  Only been here a month, been interesting.

Answer (score 0):

[Stephen Rauch’s answer](//superuser.com/q/1170407/354511#1170422) describes the problem. 
I have a different solution.

But first: why are you putting such a long command into a variable? 
Just so you can print it? 
Why not just use the shell’s verbose (show commands) option?

```
set -v
(your_command)
set +v
```

The `x` (execution trace) option is similar;
try the above with `set -x` and `set +x` to see the difference. 
If you like them both, you can combine them with `set -vx` and `set +vx`.

---

It’s a pretty bad idea to build a string out of a sequence of words,
separated by spaces,
and then try to break it apart to recover the original component words. 
You’ve encountered one of the pitfalls. 
Another is the theoretical possibility
that a filename might contain space(s);
it would be impossible to tell from the command string `cat foo bar baz`
that `foo bar` is one filename and `baz` is another
(and you’ve seen that building the string as `cat "foo bar" baz`
doesn’t work well either). 
These issues and others are discussed here:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace
  or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable
  in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216)

Also, you don’t need `printf` just to concatenate strings.

If you really want to build your command line in storage,
and you’re using bash, you can use an array variable, like this:

```
DulicityCMD=(duplicity --log-file "$LOG_FILE" --progress --no-encryption --include="/etc" --include="/var/log" --include="/var/db" --include="/var/www" --include="/home" --exclude="**" / scp://duplicity@myhost.com:22//home/duplicity/backups/"$VPSNAME")
```

Note that I put `$LOG_FILE` and `$VPSNAME` into quotes. 
You should always quote all references to shell variables
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
But Stephen is right: you don’t really need to quote constant strings
like `"/etc"`, `"/var/log"`, `"/var/db"`, and so on. 
(But, of course, you *do* need to quote `"**"`,
because **`*`** is a special character.)

For readability, you can break the above into multiple lines. 
Note that the first line says **`=`**
and the subsequent lines say **`+=`**,
because they are adding to what has come before:

```
DulicityCMD=(duplicity --log-file "$LOG_FILE" --progress --no-encryption)
DulicityCMD+=(--include="/etc" --include="/var/log" --include="/var/db")
DulicityCMD+=(--include="/var/www" --include="/home" --exclude="**")
DulicityCMD+=(/ scp://duplicity@myhost.com:22//home/duplicity/backups/"$VPSNAME")
```

Then you can do

```
printf "%s\n" "${DulicityCMD[*]}"           (to print the command)
"${DulicityCMD[@]}"                         (to execute the command)
```

or use `sudo "${DulicityCMD[@]}"`, if you need to. 
See [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for more information on bash’s syntax,
and [my answer here](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350) to see more about this array technique.